# Google Sheets + Monday.com API - Change column value

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, monday.com

I managed to connect the Monday.com API with google sheets using Scripts and create a new item in my board, however, I can only insert the item name, how can I insert a value in my column.

Code example:

```
function Create_Line() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("tests");
  var values = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var mondayAPIkey = "API_KEY"
  for(var i=1;i<values.length;i++)
  {
    if(values[i][7]=="")
    { 
      
      var query = "mutation($board:Int!, $name:String!,$colvals:JSON!){create_item(board_id:$board, item_name:$name, column_values:$colvals){id}}";
      var variables = {
                        "board" : "board_id",
                        "name" : values[i][0], //where column A has the name I want for the item
                        "colvals": JSON.stringify({ "column_id": "Coluna 1", "value": "Done"}) //calling the now formatted date variable
                       
                       };
      var pulseID = JSON.parse(makeAPICall(mondayAPIkey, query, variables)).data.create_item.id;
      sh.getRange(i+1, 8).setValue(pulseID)
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Sample Spreadsheet]

EDIT: To explain the question in a better way, the result that I'm looking for is this:

[image]

The script runs through the entire google sheets list and creates the lines on Monday.com, the problem is that I can not fill the column value

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your question, can you provide the sample value returned from `makeAPICall(mondayAPIkey, query, variables)` and sample output situation you expect? And, unfortunately, I cannot understand about `Row1` and `value` in your provided image. I apologize for this.

Comment: Just edited the question! Thanks!

Comment: So the picture that you have shared and the code does not correspond. You are  setting a value at column eight not *A*, also where is the "value". Instead of describing your current outcome, try to describe the variables you have  from the Looger and the expected outcome, so we can have a chance to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The column values argument you're passing to the monday.com API is in the wrong format. I cannot find your column ID in your original post, so I'm going to assume it's 'coluna_1'.

Try changing your variables to this:

```js
var variables = {
  "board" : YOUR_BOARD_ID,
  "name" : values[i][0],
  "colvals" : JSON.stringify({"coluna_1" : "Done"})
}
```

According to the [official monday API Quickstart](https://support.monday.com/hc/en-us/articles/360013465599):

> Our GraphQL schema defines a set of column values as a JSON string (key-value pairs). The keys of the column_values object must be column IDs, and the values must be structured depending on the type of the column.

You can find the column ID by enabling developer mode, [as described in this article.](https://support.monday.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000225709-Where-to-find-board-item-and-column-IDs)

The value depends on the column type in monday.com. You can see a list of columns supported by the monday.com API here: [API Documentation](https://monday.com/developers/v2#simple-column-values-section)